# Why sometimes doesn't ng-init trigger $watch listener?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, ng-init

I execute the follow code in my app and sometimes ng-init doesn't trigger $watch. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <p ng-init="stages = 'coco'">{{x}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

   function MyCtrl($scope) {

       $scope.$watch("stages", function() {
            alert($scope.stages);
       });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does, according to your code you have not added **`ng-app`** anywhere.

**`DEMO`**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){

       $scope.$watch("stages", function() {
            alert($scope.stages);
       });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <p ng-init="stages = 'coco'">{{x}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, is part of the code of an application. I have seen in the app log that sometimes the $watch doesn't trigger, Is it possible?.

Comment: no that cannot be, it always triggers whenever a variable is changed